# ImportError: No module named encodings

Tags: python

On a ubuntu 16.04 machine I experience since some time ago an error like this if I execute some python programs, for example `pythontex` (same with `pythontex --interpreter python:python3`)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pythontex", line 50, in <module>
    import pythontex2 as pythontex
  File "/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex2.py", line 53, in <module>
    import argparse
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 92, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext as _
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 49, in <module>
    import locale, copy, os, re, struct, sys
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 13, in <module>
    import encodings
ImportError: No module named encodings
```

`pythontex` is the program I actually needed, but the same problem occurs with `pip`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import locale
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 13, in <module>
    import encodings
ImportError: No module named encodings
```

I tried a `dpkg-reconfigure python python3 python2.7` but it didn't help. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings

Comment: Thanks, but Is the link also relevant if I didn't work with virtualenvs?

Comment: Please check if PYTHONHOME / PYTHONPATH is properly setup. It might not be able to locate the encodings if environment is not properly set up.